# What does "when shift breaks" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

The context is from the movie "taxi driver" by Martin Scorsese

The main character Travis comes to a taxi company to ask for a job as a  cabbie.

The  manager he talks to after some initial conversation  says to him:

Look, just fill out these forms and check back tomorrow when **the shift breaks.**

**break** TFD def
26. To come to an end: The cold spell broke yesterday.

Can "when the shift breaks" mean "when the shift ends"?

I tough it meant when the shift(a. A group of workers that relieve another on a regular schedule ) has a break(meaning eating lunch and stuff) but I can't find a definition for the word break being a verb that means to have a break.

Comment: It makes sense to interpret it as 'when the shift ends' - so that he can take over a taxi from a driver who has finished work. There would be no point in his coming during a lunch or coffee break.

Comment: I think the definition you found works perfectly here.

Comment: Oh Stangdon is from the Big Apple so i guess he would know if it's the other way round. Thanks guys(and galls) for the help:)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like shift breaks happen when you stop to take some water in the middle of the shift, maybe when you take a walk to stretch the legs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I know what a break is Jandrei but this doesn't make  sense as "breaks" is a verb and there is no definition for a verb "break" which denotes taking a break. As for Kate's assumption that therer would be no point in him comming during a lunch i would say that there is some rationale in it but the action takes place in New York city and there is alot of argot specific only to that particular area, so I feel like there could be a slang verb breaks(meaning take a break) and then it would mean  workers taking a break. There is no mentioning of him getting a job after all. He was just suppose.....

Comment: ....to check back with the forms filled up. Maybe the lunchtime is the time that the manager has the most time to deal with this kind of stuff cause he's got other responosibilities during the shift?

Comment: I think this is a valid interpretation of what is meant.  It could mean *when the shift ends* or it could mean *when the shift takes its break*.  My guess is *when the shift breaks* is taxi driver jargon and someone who has worked as a taxi driver (maybe even a NYC taxi driver) could clear this up for us.